# How much worthy to pay for one who keeps precepts, metta?

Tags: sila, dana

Say a soldier can be hired for maybe $100 a day: What would be a suitable price to offer that one would live in accordance with the Dhamma, keeping precepts based on metta for all beings, a day?

Comment: Keeping the precepts -- i.e. "no killing, lying, stealing, sexual misconduct, or drunkenness" -- is assumed and is essential for every job I know of. Anyone who doesn't keep those precepts wouldn't be hired for, or will be fired from, any job.

Answer (score 1):

The undoing of rebirth is one's pay.

One who is rightly striving is not looking for any other pay.

They are only looking to exhaust their time.

Answer (score 1):

> "All too many times people will break a precept and then they regret it for the rest of their lives, saying, *“I wish I had a million dollars and could go back and undo that.”* But a million dollars can’t do that. You, though, have a precept that can prevent you from doing that kind of thing, so it’s worth more than a million dollars. Think about that every time you feel tempted to do something that’s against the precepts. Your precepts are your real treasures. By holding the mind fenced in this way, you free yourself from all kinds of regret. This is how a fence can lead to freedom."

> ~ Thanissaro Bhikkhu "Virtue" https://www.dhammatalks.org/Archive/Writings/CrossIndexed/Published/Shorttalks/170730(short)_Virtue.pdf